# Converting VB.Net project from VS 2008 to VS 2013 convert warning to error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I converted by project from VS 2008 to VS 2013. But following warning in 2008 become error in 2013

> Inappropriate use of 'Overloads' keyword in a module.

It was a warning in VS 2008 but in 2013 it become error

Code :

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Overloads Sub CopyMemory(ByVal Destination As Integer, ByVal Source As Integer, ByVal Length As Integer)
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like a badly declared [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/CopyMemory.html)

Comment: The error message actually says it all.

Comment: Remove **Overloads** from the method and it will be fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules do not support "Overloads" keywords. So remove it manually. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syxdc22(v=vs.90).aspx) for restricted keywords in module.

Comment: It was working fine in VS 2008. And also  If i try to remove Overloads keyword than it still give following error 'CopyMemory' must be declared 'Overloads' because another 'CopyMemory' is declared 'Overloads' or 'Overrides'.